# My UITableView with custom xib cells disappear as soon as I start scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ToDoViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var DateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var MonthLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var DayLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var newButton: UIImageView!

    static var ToDoEvents:[event] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ToDoViewController.readFromFile()
       // let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
       // tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        //let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "customCell", bundle: nil)
       // tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")

       tableView.register(UINib(nibName: String(describing: CustomCell.self), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    public static func readFromFile(){
        ToDoViewController.ToDoEvents.append(event(eventName: "Spanish Workbook", eventLength: 3601, complete: false))
        ToDoViewController.ToDoEvents.append(event(eventName: "History Test", eventLength: 37, complete: false))
        ToDoViewController.ToDoEvents.append(event(eventName: "Lit Essay", eventLength: 40, complete: true))
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ToDoViewController.ToDoEvents.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! CustomCell
        let currentEvent = ToDoViewController.ToDoEvents[indexPath.row]
        let eventName = currentEvent.name!
        let eventLength = currentEvent.time!
        let completion = currentEvent.isComplete!
        print(eventName)
        print(eventLength)
        print(completion)

        cell.customInit(name: "\(eventName)", time: "\(eventLength)", completed: completion)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

This is my entire view controller class, but i am unable to find out why all of the data disappears as soon as I start scrolling down. The data is unable to be seen although you can see it initally. I cannot figure out why the data disappears and this the entire file. The custom init method has been shared below, although i believe that this is not the actual problem changing it.

```
func customInit(name: String, time: String, completed: Bool){
    self.eventName.text = name
    self.lengthLabel.text = time

    if(completed) {
        completedImage.image = UIImage(named: "C")
    } else {
        completedImage.image = UIImage(named: "R")
    }
    //self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 129/255.0, green: 25/255.0, blue: 207/255.0, alpha: 1)
}
```

import Foundation

class event{
    var name: String?
    var time: Int?
    var isComplete: Bool?

```
init(eventName: String, eventLength: Int) {
    self.name = eventName
    self.time = eventLength
    self.isComplete = false
}

init(eventName: String, eventLength: Int, complete: Bool) {
    self.name = eventName
    self.time = eventLength
    self.isComplete = complete
}
```

}

Comment: can you share your `customInit` method?

Comment: @Malik yes i have edited the intial post and shared the code for customInit.

Comment: Please share your event class code

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya I have updated the code with the event class code.

Comment: i checked above code in my machine it's working fine for me. 
Might be issue is some else not in table view code

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya Is there anyway for me to link you a zip file with all of my code? It seems that it doesn't work even with the changes that I have made.

Comment: yes put it in git repo share link

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya https://github.com/viditagrawal/SwiftIOS.git please take a look

Comment: I checked your code there was not any issue in Table View code 
I found issue inside Custom segue Please remove custom segue and check it's Work fine.
Also i found one issue not related to This issue it seem like that  you have used  `var vc = ToDoViewController()` in home view it's not same which you are pushing in next screen

Comment: what would be the way to fix this issue?

Comment: I think you should remove custom segue and used default Segue.

Answer (score 0):

you should change static number in numberOfRowsInSection

like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ToDoViewController.ToDoEvents.count
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to fix the problem that I am facing, can you suggest something else?

Comment: I think this answer makes sense. Your code asks for 6 rows but your data model has only 3 events. So I expect you to be unable to scroll because you have so little data.

Comment: The data still disappears when I try to scroll, even when I change it to the count of the amount of events.

Comment: Pls update your code in the question. As currently shown with 6 rows in section, but only 3 in the data, the app would crash when trying to access the data for the first of the last 3 rews

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code asked in the question.